# Debugging my first class call. Creating a circle with user input

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor, return

### The given problem was to create two Java classes, one with constructor methods and the other with a main method, calling the first.

The second half won't compile due to a "Error, cannot find symbol" with symbols   symbol:   method getArea()
and location
location: variable radius of type Circle

**Prof said to check there was something off with my usage of printf, but that's not what's causing the compile errors, is it?**

I've done some quick searching for similar problems but a lot of issues people with the same errors were having were related to their class and methods being private.

```
// Class I'm trying to call from

public class Circle
{
    double radius;
    public Circle(double r)
        {
        radius = r;
        }
    public Circle()
    {
        radius = 0.0;
    }
    public void setRadius(double r)
    {
       radius = r;
    }
    public double getRadius()
    {
        return radius;
    }
    public double area()
    {
        return Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
    }
    public double diameter()
    {
        return radius * 2.0;
    }
    public double circumference()
    {
        return Math.PI * radius * 2.0;
    }
}



// Seperate java program, used to call Circle.java

import java.util.Scanner;
public class CircleDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input;
        double value;
        Circle radius = new Circle();
        System.out.printf("Enter the radius"+
                        "of a circle");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        value = Double.parseDouble(input);
        radius.setRadius(value);
        System.out.printf("Area: " + radius.getArea()
        + "\n Diameter: " + radius.getDiameter() +
        "\nCircumference: " + radius.getCircumference());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Error output:

```
CircleDemo.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        area = radius.getArea();
                     ^
  symbol:   method getArea()
  location: variable radius of type Circle
CircleDemo.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        diameter = radius.getDiameter();
                         ^
  symbol:   method getDiameter()
  location: variable radius of type Circle
CircleDemo.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        circumference = radius.getCircumference();
                              ^
  symbol:   method getCircumference()
  location: variable radius of type Circle
3 errors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the wrong method names.

You've defined the method `circumference()`, but are calling `getCircumference()`. You've define the method `area()`, but are calling `getArea()`.

Either rename the methods in `Circle`, or change the methods called from `main`.

Answer (score 2):

Right off the bat, it appears as if you're calling the wrong methods.

If you are trying to use getters and setters in Java you have to actually create a method for getting and a method for setting. 
Java doesn't automatically give you the values if you just call getDiameter(). You need to actually create a method called getDiameter() then you can call it.

Let me know if that fixes your problem!

Answer (score 1):

You're using methods that **do not exist**. `getDiameter()`, `getArea()` and `getCircumference()` are not declared in your class Circle. I think you're trying to call `diameter()`, `area()` and `circumference()`. Getters and setters must be declared in the class with its own name; they are not automatically created or something like that.